# Powershell - remove/replace all text before certain tag

Tags: powershell

I would like to know if there is a way to remove all text from a read file before particular tag/word?

Trying to do via replace and nothing gets replaced.

```
    $Content = Get-Content $file -Raw 
    $Content.replace("*\<Document\>","") | Out-File $basePath$newFile -Append
```

And append is there to see that output once all is replaced. But it returns full file. Perhaps there is a way to remove everything before the "Document" from the text?

**Solution:**
After meditating few more times I did what I needed! Since it was an issue where the file is XML and has two root nodes:

```
<apphdr></apphdr>
<document></document>
```

The solution came to me clear as sky to check for the index of the necessary root element and remove all from zero to the index.

```
    $Content = Get-Content $file -Raw
    $endIndex = $Content.IndexOf("<Document>")
    $afterRemove = $Content.Remove(0,$endIndex) | Out-File $basePath$newFile -Append
```

And in the output file I get only XML document with those DOCUMENT tags!

Comment: Pro-tip: `replace` is _basic_ text replacement.  No patterns.  It looks like your data is xml, try loading it up as an xml document then working with structured objects.

Comment: You guessed right about the XML part... But this is not an option. It is specific file that is a faulty XML (has two root elements) therefore the solution is needed to somehow remove the first part which is not relevant.

Comment: Can you add some context about what the structure of the XML looks like in your question and which parts you want removed?

Comment: Sure, its pretty much two XML documents in one file:
`<apphdr></apphdr>
<document></document>`.

System vendor sends them like this, nothing can be done from their side. Basically would like to remove all <apphdr></apphdr> part from the file, and work with a nice XML that is left after.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (in case some miss it in the question):**
The issue was that XML file file had two root elements (broken XML logic)

```
<apphdr></apphdr>
<document></document>
```

The solution is to check for the index of the necessary root element and remove all from zero to the index.

```
$Content = Get-Content $file -Raw # read as raw text
$endIndex = $Content.IndexOf("<Document>") # find index of the Document tag
$afterRemove = $Content.Remove(0,$endIndex) | Out-File $basePath$newFile -Append # Store value after removal and conveyor to new file
```

And in the output file I get only XML document with those DOCUMENT tags!